# How to filter Realm Results<Object>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I use mongoDB to store data. I have a Result array, which array contains multiple same keyword results.

```
class Keywords: Object {
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var date: Date = Date()
@objc dynamic var rank: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var requestedURL: String = ""
}
```

Users can not send requests more than once for the same keyword name.

```
     let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { action in
        if let textSafe = text.text {
            let textPrefix = textSafe.removeWhitespace()
            
            if self.keywordModel.keywordNames.count > 0 {
                if self.keywordModel.keywordNames.contains(textSafe) {
                    return
                } else {
                    self.seo.fetchSEO(keyword: textPrefix, requestURL: self.selectedDomain!.domainName, start: 1)
                }
            } else {
                self.seo.fetchSEO(keyword: textPrefix, requestURL: self.selectedDomain!.domainName, start: 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

My codes are working fine up to this part.

But when users want to refresh to update results there I need to write filter results or somehow must get only the last recent results if keywords are multiple times stored in the database. By the way, I need multiplied keyword data results since I want to use them for date progress charts in the future.

So simply I need to save all results but I want to show only more recent results on UI.

```
@objc func refresh(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var keywordArray = [String]()
    
    keywordModel.keywordNames.forEach { keyword in
        keywordArray.append(keyword)
    }
    
    keywordModel.keywordNames = [String]()
    keywordModel.keywordRanks = [Double]()
    
    keywordArray.forEach { keyword in
        self.seo.fetchSEO(keyword: keyword, requestURL: self.selectedDomain!.domainName)
    }
    
    
    print(keyword!)
    let deadLine = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadLine) {
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    } 
}
```

And for further detail, I transfer results to KeywordModel for some calculations, and i manage all tableview through the KeywordModel codes below.

```
struct KeywordModel {
var keywordRanks = [Double]()
var averageRank: Double? = 0.0
var keywordCount: Int? = 0
var keywordNames = [String]()

var keywordCountString: String? {
    return String(keywordCount!)
}
var averageRankString: String? {
    return String(format: "%.01f", averageRank!)
}

mutating func averageOfRanks(resultKeyword: Results<Keywords>?) {
    keywordCount = resultKeyword?.count
    var n = 0
    var raw = [Double]()
        
    while n < resultKeyword!.count {
        raw.append(Double(resultKeyword![n].rank))
        n += 1
    }
    keywordRanks = raw
    
    let rankSum = keywordRanks.reduce(0, +)
    averageRank = rankSum / Double(keywordRanks.count)
}

mutating func saveKeywords(from results: Results<Keywords>?) {
    if results!.count > 0 {
        var n = 0
        var raw = [String]()
        while n < results!.count {
            raw.append(results![n].name)
            n += 1
        }
        keywordNames = raw
    }
}
```

And there is my `loadData` method, where I can apply a filter.

```
 func loadData() {
    keyword = selectedDomain?.keywords.sorted(byKeyPath: "name")
    
    statisticCalculate(keyword: keyword)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and it sounds like you're asking multiple questions - one about ensuring unique values and second about saving results and third about only showing recent results. My other concern is the title of the question `Realm result Array` because a Realm Results object is *not* an array and behaves very differently than an array. While they have a similar interface, they are very different. Can you clarify if you are using Results or an Array?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear,  `Realm Result Array` means `Results<Keyword>` array. Actually solved the issue by adding another `Statistics` table into the database. So in the `Keyword` table, I only save `rank` and `keyword name`.  And if `requested keyword` already contains in the table only update them with the new recent `rank` value, meanwhile add new value in the `Statistics` table if the previous value older than a day. But I'm still curious if I can send a fetching request by a `[String]` keyword array without a loop. Because there is a way in the `PHP` language.

Comment: This is important: `Results<Keyword> array` is NOT an array, it's a Results object. You may be overlooking a fundamental function of Realm; Realm Results objects are LIVE - as objects are added, modified or removed from Realm, the results objects always reflect those changes. So for example, if you have a Results object that contains Keywords. If you want to ensure keywords the user enters are unique, you don't have to keep querying for keywords; as they are added to Realm, they will automatically appear in the Results object so you can simply see if they exist there before adding to Realm.

Comment: I'm quite new and there are so many things to learn. Thank you very much for the information I will dig and read about it!